# Count Total Using Linq

Tags: linq

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT [degree_id], [institution_id]
FROM [dbo].[instlist]
where [degree_id]=1
group by institution_id, degree_id
```

I need to count total rows, so I then use a for loop to get count and then return it. How to convert the query above in Linq? Thanks.

```
[HttpGet]
    public int GetDegreeCountByInstitution(int degreeid)
    {
        var qry = db.instlist
                   .GroupBy(g => new { g.degree_id, g.institution_id })

                  .Select(n => new { degree_id=n.degree_id, institution_id=n.institution_id });



        var cnt=0;
        for( int i=0; i<qry.ToList().Count; i++)
        {
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }

        return cnt;
    }
```

There is an error on the select statement.

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Are you able to run this query directly from sql management studio ?

Comment: Yes. It was created using sql management studio. I am creating a web api and need to get a count of the records. I removed the distinct because it returns the same results.

Comment: .Count()? Best I can do with the provided code my friend. Will need more to be more helpful. http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-count/

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public int GetDegreeCountByInstitution(int degreeid)
        {
            var qry = db.instlist
                       .GroupBy(g => new { g.degree_id, g.institution_id })
                      
                      .Select(n => new { degree_id=n.degree_id,  institution_id=n.institution_id });
                       
                      
                     
            var cnt=0;
            for( int i=0; i<qry.ToList().Count; i++)
            {
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }

            return cnt;
        }

Comment: There is an error in the Select line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `count` for `group by`;

```
   var result = db.instlist.Where(x => x.degree_id == 1)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.degree_id, x.institution_id })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            degree_id = g.Key.degree_id,
            institution_id = g.Key.institution_id,
            count = g.Count()//Apply count for grouped records
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var q = (from id in instlist
         where id.degree_id == 1
         select id.degree_id, id.institution_id).Distinct().Count()
```